# Sort Nuget search results by number of downloads and last update

Tags: c#, nuget

When searching for packages on https://nuget.org the search results are neither sorted by the number of downloads nor by the last update date.

How can one search for NuGet packages and sort them by number of downloads and last update date? I want to find popular and regularly updated packages. I don't necessarily have to use the NuGet website, if there are other interfaces that would be also fine, thanks!